# Python Regular Expression - Match certain first characters but not a W

Tags: python, regex

I have 2 different file names that I am comparing:
PP_AUTOWELC.xml - needs to go to location 1
PP_WELCOMEKIT.xml - needs to go to location 2

There are also a bunch of other PP_Documents that need to go to location 1.

What is the regular expression to match everything "PP_" and then the next character will be anything but a "W".

I thought it was PP_[^W]*.xml but that doesn't allow any of the characters following PP_ to be a "W".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty close, actually!

```
PP_[^Ww].*\.xml
```

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/tB1dC7/1)

I added the [^Ww] because i figured you didn't want PP_welcome.xml as well as PP_Welcome.xml

Comment: Thank you for this! That website is awesome as well!

Comment: @user2347550 no problem! Don't forget to accept an answer if it solves your problem!